# resolv.conf containing 127.0.0.1

Tags: 12.04, dns, ipv6

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a dual-stack network (with managed IPv6 configuration). I would like to verify if the DNS resolver options received from DHCP and DHCPv6 servers are correct.

Normally, I would check `/etc/resolv.conf`, but on Ubuntu it contains only `127.0.0.1`. It would be a bit far-fetched to assume that Ubuntu is running a recursive DNS resolver by default, so I think the actual resolver settings are somewhere else.

Where would I check this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use **nm-tool**, to check which DNS-server you are using right know.

just run nm-tool without any parameters. Here is the interesting part from the output:

```
[...]
IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.5.126
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.5.1

    DNS:             192.168.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your resolv.conf contains 127.0.0.1 and your DNS resolving is working then you probably *are* running a local resolver or proxy...

DHCP related configuration can often be found in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: It's `dnsmasq`, but it does not recurse from root servers down, just forwards the query to the specified DNS resolvers. It is installed by default in 12.04.